# VS build successful regardless of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm creating a C++ library in Visual Studio 2015. The project builds "successfully" when it clearly shouldn't. For example it builds if I type garbage into a source file. I would like to be warned when I haven't overridden a pure virtual function, but instead I get no feedback at all.

Here's a video demonstrating exactly what's going on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pj7a4L36_ns

Can anyone offer some insight into this?

Comment: Then probably you are building not what you think you are... Update: Taken time and watched the video. You are changing some unrelated header file which is not even included anywhere...

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding. In the video the file was accessed using VS's solution explorer which shows it is related to the project, and it is included in another header file "ocwl.h". This other file is not included anywhere but I don't see why it should be included anywhere when building a library.

Comment: If there is no source files to build, these headers won't even be looked at by the compiler..

Comment: Look at build logs, not moving pictures.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh., that was the crucial bit I didn't know. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EugeneSh. explained, "If there is no source files to build, these headers won't even be looked at by the compiler."

To get the C2259 "cannot instantiate abstract class" error which I was expecting, an instance of the subclass has to be declared in code, in a source (not header) file.

This was caused by a lack in understanding of what goes on under the hood, and how source and header files relate.